# Setting breakpoints and autocomplete in C9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

Just start to use cloud 9 IDE and however I tried I just can't make simple breakpoints. I looked for solution in different tutorials and on YouTube it seems like something is wrong because setting breakpoint should be done with one mouse click and yet nothing, it should be very straight forward and yet...It just don't happen no matter how hard I try. So please, any advise on that would be appreciated.

Also, the code autocomplete is not working, so again-your help is welcomed.

Rgds

Ron

Answer (score 3):

clicking in the gutter (the gray area) should just work. Then running the app should hit the breakpoint. This works for node.js development only at the moment. Code completion works when you hit ALT+SPACE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying with JavaScript file?

I've tried to set breakpoint with ruby(.rb) file and it didn't work, but with JavaScript file it worked.

I'm not sure about which language C9 fully supports. Maybe you should try with JavaScript file first.